# Using GAE version of django

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, django-nonrel, djangoappengine

I have a django application that runs on Google App Engine. I use [djangoappengine](https://github.com/django-nonrel/djangoappengine) and [django-nonrel](https://github.com/django-nonrel/django) and it works fine (with the complete source code of django in my App Engine project dir).
I've noticed that GAE offers support for django by adding the following lines to `app.yaml`:

```
libraries:
- name: django
  version: 1.5
```

I would like to use it instead of putting the entire django-nonrel source code in my project dir.
When I remove django-nonrel from my project dir, I get the following ImportError from `djangoappengine/boot.py`:

```
ImportError: No module named django.conf
```

It looks like djangoappengine can't find any version of django - not the one installed on my python installation, and not the ones come with AppEngine.

How can I make the dev server use the AppEngine version of django?
Or am I missing something?

**Update:**
When I manually edit `djangoappengine/boot.py` and add

```
sys.path.append(r'<PATH TO GAE API>/google_appengine/lib/django-1.5')
```

It works. Any way to add to the path without editing `djangoappengine`?

Comment: You also need to `import django` in your appropriate module.

Comment: Thanks @AshishNitinPatil for the response. What do you mean by 'appropriate module'? Won't `import django` raise the same `ImportError` as `import django.conf` raises?

Comment: Nope. I think, the `app.yaml` directs the server to have `django` as an external library included for the server. Thus, `import django` won't fail. (I may be wrong though)

Comment: @AshishNitinPatil I've just tried `import django` and it raises the same error. Any other ideas?

Comment: If `djangoappengine` has `django-nonrel` as a dependancy (& I think it does), in that case, I am afraid you'll have to include the `django-nonrel` package.

Comment: Please use the django bundled with django-nonrel. It's different from the django modulde available in GAE runtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Django module included with the GAE SDK is "regular" Django, not django-nonrel.  "regular" Django can only deal with SQL databases, it can't deal with GAE's datastore.

If you're using CloudSQL, use "regular" Django.  If you're using the HRD datastore, use django-nonrel.

The error you're seeing is because djangoappengine (and djangotoolbox) only work with django-nonrel.  They won't work with "regular" django.

Comment: Thanks. Just for clarification - the 'regular' django can also be used if using the GAE model directly (db and ndb).

Comment: Yes. But it's hard to come up with a good reason to do that since many of the builtins, like the forms, most of the contrib libraries, and most 3rd party plugins won't work.  You're probably better off going with webapp2+jinja in that case.

Comment: My reason of doing it is that I need very optimized Data Store queries, which is hard or maybe impossible to achieve using the django-nonrel wrapping of the Data Store queries. For normal use, I totally agree.